# Who first introduced the term "categorical group", and when?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview, monoidal-categories

The term "categorical group" is often used to mean a group object in Cat; these days we also call such a thing a [strict 2-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-group#Strict_2-groups).  **Who first introduced the term "categorical group", and when?** Perhaps it appeared in the French literature under some name like "groupe catégorique"?

Here are some things I know, which don't answer my question, but might provide clues. In 1973 Hoàng Xuân Sính finished [her thesis](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/lexmath/kuenzer/sinh.html) with Grothendieck on a more general concept, which she called "Gr-catégories"; these are now also called [2-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-group).   In 1978 she published this paper:

- Hoàng Xuân Sính, [Gr-catégories strictes](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/lexmath/kuenzer/Hoang_Xuan_Sinh_Gr_categories_strictes.pdf), *Acta Mathematica Vietnamica* **3** (2) (1978), 47--59.

Strict Gr-categories are the same as categorical groups, but I don't think she uses a term like "groupe catégorique" anywhere in this paper.  In this paper she proves (among other things) that every Gr-category is equivalent to a strict one, and that you can get strict ones from crossed modules.

Earlier, Brown and Spencer wrote a related paper:

- Ronald Brown and C. B. Spencer, [$\mathcal{G}$-groupoids, crossed modules, and the classifying space of a topological group](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82096733.pdf), *Proc. Kon. Akad. v. Wet.* **79** (1976), 296-302.

$\mathcal{G}$-groupoids are the same as categorical groups, but they don't use the term "categorical group" anywhere.  In this paper they prove (among other things) that you can get $\mathcal{G}$-groupoids from crossed modules and vice versa.  They write:

> This result was, we understand, known to Verdier in 1965; it was then used by Duskin [6] ; it was discovered independently by us in 1972. The work of Verdier and Duskin is unpublished, we have found that Theorem 1 is little known, and so we hope that this account will prove useful.

Reference [6] is to an unpublished paper which I have not located:

- J. Duskin, Preliminary remarks on groups. Unpublished notes, Tulane University, 1969.

The first actual use of the term "categorical group" that I've found comes considerably later:

- A. Solian, Coherence in categorical groups, *Comm. Algebra* **9** (1981), 1039-1057.

However, this paper actually deals with with 2-groups, not the strict 2-groups = strict Gr-categories that are nowadays often meant by the term "categorical group".

Also in 1981 there is a paper in German that uses the term "Kategorie mit Gruppenstruktur":

- K.-H. Ulbrich, [Kohärenz in Kategorien mit Gruppenstruktur](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869381902957), J. Algebra, 72 (1981), pp. 279-295.

but again this is about 2-groups in general, not the strict ones, and I don't see the term "categorical group" (or some German equivalent) anywhere in this paper.